Can i automatically create container specific placeholders and references in draw.io?
I've created a template for a draw.io container which holds multiple placeholders and references those.
Example:
The container template holds name, gender and age placeholder fields which are editable. The placeholder fields are referenced in a text field, resulting in a full sentence:

placeholder: unique_id - edited to "001"
placeholder: name - edited to "Thomas"
placeholder: gender - edited to "male"
placeholder: age - edited to "35"

The full sentence looks like this: "Container 001 - Thomas is of gender male and is 35 years old."
What do i want to do?
I want to use this container template to create numerous containers which should all be editable on their own. If i use the template and edit placeholder fields i'm changing the values in all of the containers. I don't want to edit or enumerate the placeholders in the seperate containers by hand and i'm searching for a workaround to automatically enumerate / differ these when copying the container.
Editing the containers by hand is tedious as i will have a couple hundred containers - i have not found a way to enumerate / edit the placeholders when copying them or creating them from my default template.
